# laptop fan switches off at linux boot

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, fan, cooling, hp-pavilion

Laptop is HP pavalion dv6000 with intel+ge7400. The CPU fan runs during bios screen+grub and right after linux (ubuntu 9 based mint) starts loading, it switches off. What could be the reason.

Thanks,
vikas

Comment: Starting fans (usually at max speed) when a system boots is normal. Afterwards control of the fan speed is usually taken over by the OS, with a few hardware exceptions which can overrule things (e..g do an emergency shutdown what things get to hot, when PROCHOT is asserted etc).  This matches what you write: Fan on. Kernel loads (and takes on responsibility),. Kernel settings switch the fan on when needed (and off or wslow when not needed).

Answer (score 0):

The fan probably is running until the daemon which controls it loads. At that point, since the CPU is relatively cool, the fan is not needed, so the system shuts it off.  If you do CPU-intensive work like rendering video or playing 3D games, the fan will probably switch back on.  Certainly that is how my own DV6000 running Ubuntu acts.

Comment: i could not find any driver that that has access to my laptop fan. HP says, to save battery fan only runs when needed (ie. >50deg) - like you are suggesting but its at hardware not software level. I only wonder, how come it runs even when grub selector is visible. and then instantly off when linux boot starts.

Comment: Do you get the same fan behavior if you boot a LiveCD, or a Widnows partition if you have one?